# Instagram API returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, instagram-api

When I run the server.js app I get this error:

```
{ SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at IncomingMessage. (/Users/test/Desktop/simple_node_app/node_modules/instagram-node/lib/instagram.js:192:27)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
retry: [Function: retry],
status_code: 404,
etc, etc...
```

I tested the token with an API call from the browser, it works when it is standalone, but the server.js file keeps throwing this error. 
Here are my versions:

```
"dependencies": {
"ejs": "^2.5.6",
"express": "^4.15.2",
"instagram-node": "^0.5.8"
}
```

server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var ig      = require('instagram-node').instagram();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

ig.use({
  access_token: "MY_ACCESS_TOKEN"
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // console.log(req);
    // use the instagram package to get popular media
        ig.user_self_feed(function(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {
        // render the home page and pass in the popular images
        console.log(err);
        res.render('pages/index', { grams: medias });
    });
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('App started! Look at http://localhost:8080');
```

The access token works, when I use this API, I get JSON:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=12345 (not real, of course...)

Comment: n1t0 published 2 years ago. Probably the package is out of date.

Comment: I guess, that api that you're trying to consume might be returning an error in html format, which is why you're getting this Unexpected token error.

Comment: @DavidR I will take a look when I get home, I think you're right, it might be the 404 page in HTML. I'll let you know.

Comment: @hisener what is n1t0? I don't recognize that name.

Comment: @CaptainChaos owner of the package. (instagram-node)

Comment: @hisener, my instinct is that you are right. I'll have to dig around and see if there is a different lib for instagram and node that works. If that doesn't work, I'll have to try twitter or pinterest or something for Node. If you have any recommendations for IG, TW or PI, I'd be grateful. Either way I'll be posting the results of my research here.

Comment: I'll research some other instagram libs for node. In the meantime, does anyone have one they recommend?